# .NET Core 5 Console Logging using Serilogs

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have written a console application using .NET Core 5 and it uses the Serilog for the logging.

Everything is working as expected except when I try to pass the ILogger to another class in different project but in the same solution - I am getting an exception

"Error  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<TestUpdater.TestUProcess>' to 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<TestUpdater.Service.MyService>'"

Here my code
Program.cs

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Read/Load appsettings json
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            BuildConfig(builder);

            //Setup Serilog
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Build())
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.File(@"Log\Log.log")
                .CreateLogger();

            Log.Logger.Information("Application Starting");

            var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddTransient<IMyUProcess, MyUProcess>();
                })
                .UseSerilog()
                .Build();

            var svc = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<RIUProcess>(host.Services);
            svc.Run(args);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Logger.Error(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    static void BuildConfig(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT")}", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    }
```

Here my solution structure

Solution: MyUpdater.sln

Project1: MyUpdater

Class: Program.cs  -- code for this class as shown above

Using DI it passing the logger and config to Process.cs

Class: Process.cs

```
        public Process(ILogger<RIUProcess> log, IConfiguration config)
        {
            this._log = log;
            this._config = config;
        }

        public void Run(string[] args)
        {
            .. some code
            MyService _service = new MyService(this._log, this._config)
        }
```

Project2: MyUpdater.Service

class:  MyService

```
private readonly ILogger<MyService> _log;
public MyService(ILogger<MyService> log, IConfiguration config)
{
    this._log = log;  **--- This line causing the error as show above**
    this._config = config;
    bridgeDAO = new BridgeDAO(config.GetConnectionString("BentleyReadOnlyDatabase"));
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please elaborate on _"when I try to pass the ILogger to another class in different project but in the same solution"_ (preferably show the code)?

Comment: Try to use the not generic version in the "other" class. `ILogger` instead of `ILogger<MyService>`. Or resolve the service through DI instead of manually instantiate it

Comment: @GuruStron I have updated the original request with code you requested

Comment: @Kalten Yes it resolve the error but I think the problem with using generic ILogger is when exception happen it shows class as MyProcess instead MyService ?

Comment: @dotnetdev. Yes, with not generic you will share the same log category. This is why I also suggest to resolve your service with DI. You can also use an ILoggerFactory and build the right generic logger on demand.

Comment: @Kalten can you please provide me the same sample code?